# custom animation with delay to change text color

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a simple animation on a `ul` using jquery.

Let's say that each `li` element has a font color (say black). I want to make it so that each 5 seconds the next element in the `ul` will change it's color to red. So: page load, wait 5 seconds and element 1 will change to red, wait 5 seconds and element 2 will do and again till the end of the `ul`. I was trying to use delay but will not work with `.css` as far as I know but only with anymations.

```js
    $('#risultato li').each(function(index) {
        $(this).css('color', 'grey')
           .delay(index*1500)
           .css('color', 'black');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <ul id="risultato">
        <li>Elemento 1</li>
        <li>Elemento 2</li>
        <li>Elemento 3</li>
        <li>Elemento 4</li>
        <li>Elemento 5</li>
    </ul>
```

How can I achieve my goal? Obviously this will work:

```js
$('#risultato li').each(function(index) {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'orange')
           .delay(index * 1500)
           .fadeOut(1500);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <ul id="risultato">
        <li>Elemento 1</li>
        <li>Elemento 2</li>
        <li>Elemento 3</li>
        <li>Elemento 4</li>
        <li>Elemento 5</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you're hoping? I've just created a function that adds a highlight class to the `li`, and cycles through it using `setTimeout`.
The code is fully commented.

Let me know if you were hoping for something else.

---

```js
// Highlight function
function highlight() {

  // Add highlight class to first li element that isn't highlighted
  $("#risultato li:not(.highlight)").first().addClass('highlight');

  // Check if any more li exist without the highlight class
  // (This avoids an endless loop)
  // Repeat process
  if ($("#risultato li:not(.highlight)").length != 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      highlight();
    }, 1000);
  }

}

// Trigger initial function
highlight()
```

```css
li.highlight {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="risultato">
  <li>Elemento 1</li>
  <li>Elemento 2</li>
  <li>Elemento 3</li>
  <li>Elemento 4</li>
  <li>Elemento 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No, that's what I was looking for. I was hoping to keep a full jquery solution but I understand that this is something impossible to achieve. Thanks, your code is fully valid!